# Solved inputted algebraic equation python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

If a user inputs a string like "y=3x+2", how do I change the "x" in the user's input to a SymPy Symbol named `x`?
I have tried:

```
e1 = 'y = 3x+2'
y = parse_expr(e1, evaluate=True)
```

but an error is raised when I try to parse `e1`.

I don't want to use a regex or split the values into separate variables because there could be completely different formats of formulas.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  Many other people have attacked this problem; you should incorporate their solutions into your question here.

Answer (score 2):

After parsing the user string (after taking care of the `=`) you no longer have a string, you have a python expression in which are SymPy objects. The `x` will now be a generic Symbol, just like the one you assigned to the variable `x`. Here I just split on the `=` and feed the left and right hand sides into an `Equality` expression:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> user = 'y=3*x+2'
>>> y = parse_expr('Eq(%s,%s)' % tuple(user.split('=')))
>>> y
Eq(y, 3*x + 2)
>>> y.subs(x,3)
Eq(y, 11)
```

You will *not* need to replace the `x` with anything before using `solve` to solve the equation(s):

```
>>> solve(y, x)
[y/3 - 2/3]
```

You can read the `solve` docstring to see how to solve more than one equation.

You will need to read about how to get `parse_expr` to recognize implied multiplication -- note that in my example I used a proper python expression on both sides of the `=`.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you want this is what you are asking for

modify the equation:

```
3x-y=-2
4x-y=2


    import numpy as np
    a = np.array([[3, -1], [4,-1]])
    b= np.array([-2,2])
    z=np.linalg.solve(a,b)
```

Answer z =

```
array([ 4., 14.])
```